Code Changes Not Reflecting in Dockerized Express TypeScript App with PostgreSQL and Minio
I'm building docker with Express Typescript + Postgresql + Minio. I'm having a problem where when I change the code, it doesn't update the change.
docker-compose.yml:
# **Stage 1: Build (node:alpine)**
FROM node:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn

COPY . .

# **Stage 2: Development (node:alpine)**
FROM builder AS dev

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["yarn", "dev"]

Dockerfile:
version: "3.9"
services:
  server-booking:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: dev
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - minio
      - postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_HOST: postgres
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    restart: always
    networks:
      - my-booking-network

  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio-booking
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
      - "9001:9001"
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: minio
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: minio123
    command: server /data --console-address ":9001"
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    networks:
      - my-booking-network

  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres-booking
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - my-booking-network

volumes:
  minio-data:
    driver: local
  postgres-data:
    driver: local

networks:
  my-booking-network:`

Please help me. Thank you very much!
I did
docker-compose up --build -d 

but it still doesn't work
